# Meaning behind Agent Coulson's number plate (easter egg?)

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, reference, iron-man-2

At the end of *Iron Man 2*, we see Coulson arrive in the New Mexico desert in a silver car. We are treated to a somewhat unnecessary close up of the car's number plate.

8RE-2Z1

Everything in the MCU seems to be a reference to something. Is there some hidden meaning to this?

Comment: No one ever listens to me when I explain it's Eitri (maker of Thor's hammer) and a sound that fly make - "zzi". The fly being Loki.

Comment: Eitri makes so much sense, not sure I follow the Loki logic though :)

Comment: In the oroginal myth Loki, in the form of fly, was trying to interrupt Eitri in making 3 things he bet Eitri can't make. A ring, spear and Mjolnir.

Answer (score 1):

### It is a vanity plate spelling of the word "Breezy."

Colson's character in the MCU is depicted as kind of a light-hearted guy, which is in contrast to the stoic, ultra-serious "government man" type of character you would expect. He collects super hero cards, he has a sense of humor, he jokes around and is self-deprecating. One might describe his personality as "breezy."

Comment: If the 2 was a 3, I might buy this.  But "Brezzy" (which is what that plate would spell if this was correct) makes no sense.